# Why do I get VBA error 4605: "macro is running" on MailMerge.OpenDataSource?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a setup with one Excel workbook and one Word document which creates a set of customer delivery notes. The data for the notes is in the Excel book, and the Word document uses Mail Merge to create a printable document from it. The process is controlled by a VBA macro on the Excel side, which starts Word, opens the Word document and then calls a VBA macro in the Word document, which does the actual Mail Merge job.

I have used this weekly for about a year, and it has worked perfectly fine. But all of a sudden last week, the Word macro started throwing error 4605! This now occurs consistently, and on both Windows machines where I run it.

Trying to find answers, I have learned that 4605 is a very common error, indicating just about any reason that a statement in a macro cannot be executed. In my case, the statement is MailMerge.OpenDataSource, and the reason given is "because a macro is running". See code below.

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the parameters to OpenDataSource, I have tried to alter them in various ways. It appears rather that the call as such is forbidden for some reason.
I have also tried to introduce a delay before the offending call, in case there is some hidden macro that needs to complete first. And I have tried pausing the Excel macro right after calling the Word macro. But no luck.

```
Public Sub PopulatePrintExit(odbcFile As String, pdfFile As String)

    On Error GoTo closeThis
    
   With ThisDocument.MailMerge
        .OpenDataSource Name:= _
            odbcFile, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
            ReadOnly:=True, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:= _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=OdbcFile;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Typ", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Fraktsedelsdata$` WHERE (`Aviseringsnr` IS NOT null And `Aviseringsnr` <> '')"
            
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        On Error GoTo closeAll
        .Execute
    End With
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I omitted the Word macro altogether, and moved the statements into the Excel macro instead. Then it worked!

Still curious as to why this happened in the first place, though...

Comment: Kindly share us some code snippet so we can get information and set it on our project because we are facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly @MohammedAhsan! This is how I have done it in my Excel macro:

```
    Dim wordapp As Word.Application
    Dim worddoc As Word.Document

    ' Open Word...
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    '... in the background
    wordapp.Visible = False
    
    ' Open the template document
    Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(Filename:="path to Word template", Revert:=True, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)

    ' Execute mail merge, with data from this workbook
   With worddoc.MailMerge
        .OpenDataSource Name:= _
            WorkbookPath() & ThisWorkbook.Name, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
            ReadOnly:=True, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:= _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=OdbcFile;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Typ", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Fraktsedelsdata$` WHERE (`Butik` = 'Ja' AND `Antal kartonger` > 0)"
            
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute
    End With
    
    ' The created merge is now the active document instead of the template,and can be exported or saved
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="the path of the result file", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

    'Close Word
    wordapp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```